# Properly refreshing a React Native app after adding a file (running with debugger)

Tags: debugging, react-native

When I add a file I re-run the packager by pressing ^C and running:

```
...node_modules/react-native/packager/launchPackager.command; exit;
```

This breaks the app running on the Android device. It cannot connect to the development server. I run:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Then I manually reload the app.
Most times, at this point, it won't connect to the Debugger. I will close the debugger window and manually reload the app. Sometimes it opens a new debugger (or two) and all is good. Other times the packager gets stuck and won't transform the files. At this point I either wait or I simply go the brute force way with:

```
react-native run-android
```

Is there a good way of re-running the packager gracefully?

Comment: I have the same issue, the issue only seems to happen on android for me. iOS seems to work fine with the packager. What RN version are you on?

Comment: I am using RN 0.34.1